# R, opencpu: what exactly is my server address of virtual machine

Tags: ubuntu, server, virtual-machine, opencpu

I am trying to hold a virtual machine opencpu server.

I am using [VMware Workstation](https://www.vmware.com/products/player/playerpro-evaluation.html) ubuntu system. I followed the instruction of the [opencpu manual](https://opencpu.github.io/server-manual/opencpu-server.pdf) session 2.1 and 2.2, in which it says

> After installation is done, we should be able to open a browser and
>   point it to the /ocpu path at server address e.g:
>   http(s)://your.server.com/ocpu. If the welcome page shows up, the
>   installation has succeeded.

But what exactly is the `http(s)://your.server.com/ocpu` of my virtual machine? Or how could I find it?

Thanks! This is my first time using virtual machine.

**Edit**

I typed `sudo tail /var/log/apache2/error.log`, the terminal returns 
[image]

Seems the server is ready. But I just don't know what is the address that I can use on a browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a browser on the virtual machine, then you can probably use either `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` because both of those basically mean "this machine."

However, if you want to access the ocpu server from the host, or from another machine, it gets more fiddly, because you're dependent upon the networking set up for VMware.

So start by running `ifconfig` on your virtual machine.  This command lists out the network interfaces that the vm has.

You'll probably see several, and each will look something like this:

```
greg@greg-mint ~ $ ifconfig
wlan6     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a4:4e:31:28:f1:c8  
          inet addr:192.168.0.102  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a64e:31ff:fe28:f1c8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:76997 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:40778 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:61266175 (61.2 MB)  TX bytes:6456888 (6.4 MB)
```

In my case, I'd use `192.168.0.102` - see it next to `inet addr`?  Probably also the `inet6 addr` would work.

If that doesn't work, you'll have to check how the vmware networking is configured.  This page has a reasonable outline: https://www.vmware.com/support/ws45/doc/network_configure_ws.html I've always found that a bridged network seems to work easiest, the other options get into network engineer space very quickly.

Comment: I am also having this issue with opencpu in Oracle VM in win 10, and the same "all ok" message with "tail /var/log/apache2/error.log". And I have also used machine ip given by iconfig. And also tried 127.0.0.1 or localhost but no one of them is working (in the browser). Any idea what should be done? - Also unchecked firewall totally to test if the block is taking place there, but still issue persists.

Comment: ....And in VM-network settings Bridged Adapter.